# How to loop through an array

Tags: python, arrays

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a = a[i-2]
    print(a)
```

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable
```

So I am getting this index error, when i am trying to loop through my array. A is my array. I looked up the error invalid index to scalar variable online but it looks like its a case by case basis. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Ive tried replacing the for loop to this:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a = a(i-2)
    print(a)
```

But that doesn't work and throws up this error.

```
'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 1):

You should generally not attempt to change the variable you are looping over. Here you are looping over `a` and then changing `a` at each iteration of the loop.

This will work though

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

for i in range(len(a)):
    print(a[i-2])
```

You probably need to include an explanation of what it is you are trying to achieve so people can better help you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Eric's answer, you should be modifying the [i-2] part since that you'll end up trying to access an invalid element like a[-1]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `a=[1,2,3,4]`, if you do

```
for i in range(len(a)):
 b = a[i]
 print(b)
```

should output

```
1
2
3
4
```

There were a two issues from what I could tell.

1. you overwrite `a` after your first loop (a goes from array to scalar)
2. you were using the indices (0,1,2,3) to ask for positions -2,-1, 0, 1 of the `a` array. Note the first two don't exist.